How can I use a localized date format with react-datepicker?
I'm using react-datepicker with react-intl. What I want is for the date in the date picker to look like "Jan. 1, 2024" in en-US, and the correct equivalent for other locales. I believe this is called a medium dateStyle.
I know react-intl has this information, because I'm currently using it to generate the date in the correct format and feeding it into a customInput as an override value, but this makes it very difficult to let the user edit the text of the date by keyboard.
Basically, what I want is, when the locale is en-US, set dateFormat to "MMM dd, yyyy", when en-GB, set it to "dd MMM yyyy" etc.

It was right there in the date-fns docs; the answer is dateFormat="PP".
